# How to sanitize a df according to specific variable values?

Tags: r, dataframe, extract, sanitize

I have two data frames. `dfOne` is made like this:

```
 X Y Z T J
 3 4 5 6 1
 1 2 3 4 1
 5 1 2 5 1
```

and `dfTwo` is made like this

```
 C.1  C.2
  X    Z
  Y    T
```

I want to obtain a new dataframe where there are simultaneously `X`, `Y`, `Z`, `T` Values which are major than a specific threshold.

Example. I  need **simultaneously** (in the same row):

- `X, Y > 2`
- `Z, T > 4`

I need to use the second data frame to reach my objective, I expect something like:

```
dfTwo$C.1>2
```

so the result would be a new dataframe with this structure:

```
 X Y Z T J
 3 4 5 6 1
```

How could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `purrr` package

Here is the input data.

```
# Data frame from lmo's solution
dat <-
  structure(list(X = c(3L, 1L, 5L), Y = c(4L, 2L, 1L), Z = c(5L, 
                                                             3L, 2L), T = c(6L, 4L, 5L), J = c(1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("X", 
                                                                                                                        "Y", "Z", "T", "J"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                 -3L))

# A numeric vector to show the threshold values
# Notice that columns without any requirements need NA   
vals <- c(X = 2, Y = 2, Z = 4, T = 4, J = NA)
```

Here is the implementation

```
library(purrr)

map2_dfc(dat, vals, ~ifelse(.x > .y | is.na(.y), .x, NA)) %>% na.omit()

# A tibble: 1 x 5
      X     Y     Z     T     J
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     3     4     5     6     1
```

`map2_dfc` loop through each column in `dat` and each value in `vals` one by one with a defined function. `~ifelse(.x > .y | is.na(.y), .x, NA)` means if the number in each column is larger than the corresponding value in `vals`, or `vals` is `NA`, the output should be the original value from the column. Otherwise, the value is replaced to be `NA`. The output of `map2_dfc(dat, vals, ~ifelse(.x > .y | is.na(.y), .x, NA))` is a data frame with `NA` values in some rows indicating that the condition is not met. Finally, `na.omit` removes those rows.

#### Update

Here I demonstrate how to covert the `dfTwo` dataframe to the `vals` vector in my example.

First, let's create the `dfTwo` data frame.

```
dfTwo <- read.table(text = "C.1  C.2
X    Z
Y    T",
                     header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dfTwo
  C.1 C.2
1   X   Z
2   Y   T
```

To complete the task, I load the `dplyr` and `tidyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
```

Now I begin the transformation of `dfTwo`. The first step is to use `stack` function to convert the format.

```
dfTwo2 <- dfTwo %>%
  stack() %>%
  setNames(c("Col", "Group")) %>%
  mutate(Group = as.character(Group))
dfTwo2
  Col Group
1   X   C.1
2   Y   C.1
3   Z   C.2
4   T   C.2
```

The second step is to add the threshold information. One way to do this is to create a look-up table showing the association between `Group` and `Value`

```
threshold_df <- data.frame(Group = c("C.1", "C.2"),
                           Value = c(2, 4),
                           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

threshold_df
  Group Value
1   C.1     2
2   C.2     4
```

And then we can use the `left_join` function to combine the data frame.

```
dfTwo3 <- dfTwo2  %>% left_join(threshold_dt, by = "Group")
dfTwo3
  Col Group Value
1   X   C.1     2
2   Y   C.1     2
3   Z   C.2     4
4   T   C.2     4
```

Now it is the third step. Notice that there is a column called `J` which does not need any threshold. So we need to add this information to `dfTwo3`. We can use the `complete` function from `tidyr`. The following code completes the data frame by adding `Col` in `dat` but not in `dfTwo3` and `NA` to the Value.

```
dfTwo4 <- dfTwo3 %>% complete(Col = colnames(dat))
dfTwo4
# A tibble: 5 x 3
    Col Group Value
  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1     J  <NA>    NA
2     T   C.2     4
3     X   C.1     2
4     Y   C.1     2
5     Z   C.2     4
```

The fourth step is arrange the right order of `dfTwo4`. We can achieve this by turning `Col` to factor and assign the level based on the order of the column name in `dat`.

```
dfTwo5 <- dfTwo4 %>%
  mutate(Col = factor(Col, levels = colnames(dat))) %>%
  arrange(Col) %>%
  mutate(Col = as.character(Col))  
dfTwo5
# A tibble: 5 x 3
    Col Group Value
  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1     X   C.1     2
2     Y   C.1     2
3     Z   C.2     4
4     T   C.2     4
5     J  <NA>    NA
```

We are almost there. Now we can create `vals` from `dfTwo5`.

```
vals <- dfTwo5$Value
names(vals) <- dfTwo5$Col
vals
 X  Y  Z  T  J 
 2  2  4  4 NA
```

Now we are ready to use the `purrr` package to filter the data.

The aboved are the breakdown of steps. We can combine all these steps into the following code for simlicity.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
threshold_df <- data.frame(Group = c("C.1", "C.2"),
                           Value = c(2, 4),
                           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dfTwo2 <- dfTwo %>%
  stack() %>%
  setNames(c("Col", "Group")) %>%
  mutate(Group = as.character(Group)) %>%
  left_join(threshold_df, by = "Group") %>%
  complete(Col = colnames(dat)) %>%
  mutate(Col = factor(Col, levels = colnames(dat))) %>%
  arrange(Col) %>%
  mutate(Col = as.character(Col))

vals <- dfTwo2$Value
names(vals) <- dfTwo2$Col
```

Comment: it is a problem for me to assign thresholds to every variable (es. X = 2, Y = 2, etc). The second data frame is meant to simplify that process step. Actually, in my real problem I am working with more than 140 variables, clusterized on 14 different groups. So I need to integrate the step of using the dfTwo to reach my objective.

Comment: I see. Once I have access to my computer, I can show you how to convert the dfTwo to a vector. I will keep you posted.

Comment: @Silvia Please see my update. I provided a breakdown of how to create `vals` from `dfTwo`. I hope this helps.

Comment: I have solved all the problems. Thank you for your helpfulness. It works perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base R method with `Map` and `Reduce`.

```
# build lookup table of thresholds relative to variable name
vals <- setNames(c(2, 2, 4, 4), unlist(dat2))
# subset data.frame
dat[Reduce("&", Map(">", dat[names(vals)], vals)), ]
  X Y Z T J
1 3 4 5 6 1
```

Here, `Map` returns a list of length 4 with logical variables corresponding to each comparison. This list is passed to `Reduce` which returns a single logical vector with length corresponding to the number of rows in the data.frame, dat. This logical vector is used to subset dat.

**data**

```
dat <-
structure(list(X = c(3L, 1L, 5L), Y = c(4L, 2L, 1L), Z = c(5L, 
3L, 2L), T = c(6L, 4L, 5L), J = c(1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("X", 
"Y", "Z", "T", "J"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

dat2 <-
structure(list(C.1 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("X", "Y"), class = "factor"), 
    C.2 = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("T", "Z"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("C.1", 
"C.2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dfOne[Reduce(intersect, list(which(dfOne["X"] > 2),
                             which(dfOne["Y"] > 2),
                             which(dfOne["Z"] > 4),
                             which(dfOne["T"] > 4))),]
#  X Y Z T J
#1 3 4 5 6 1
```

Or iteratively (so fewer inequalities are tested):

```
vals = c(X = 2, Y = 2, Z = 4, T = 4) # from @lmo's answer
dfOne[Reduce(intersect, lapply(names(vals), function(x) which(dfOne[x] > vals[x]))),]
#  X Y Z T J
#1 3 4 5 6 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this assuming that the second DF is meant to categorize the fields in the first DF. It's way simpler if you don't need to use the second one to define the conditions:

```
dfNew = dfOne[dfOne$X > 2 & dfOne$Y > 2 & dfOne$Z > 4 & dfOne$T > 4, ]
```

Or, using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
dfNew = dfOne %>% filter(X > 2 & Y > 2 & Z > 4 & T > 4)
```

In case that's all you need, I'll save this comment while I poke at the more complicated version of the question.

Comment: The second one is meant to categorized the variables, because in the real problem I have 140 different variables and 14 variable clusters. So I need an algorithm which let me define the conditions (es. > 2) a single time for all the variable contained on each cluster.